# how to convert an X,Y motion based on a rotated point to X,Y motion on a coordinate grid?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need to move a point "A" that is rotated by "B" degrees by "C" squares to it's left, and "D" squares up. However I am only allowed to specify motion in (X motion, Y motion) based around a regular upright coordinate grid. So how do I calculate the motion in the global X,Y motiond when given the local B rotation, and C and D motions? I am programming a game and I need to know how to move my character sideways and forward using only global x and y motion.

Comment: Can you provide a picture? I think I get it, but I want to make sure before I type an answer

Comment: @Andrei Just type it in a comment first and I will see if its right, cant rlly do a pic rn

Comment: GlobalXMotion = Math.cos(Rotation)*XMotion;
GlobalYMotion = Math.sin(Rotation)*YMotion;

This does not work for me so I am confused lol

Answer (score 0):

You did not decompose the motion correctly. Let's assume first that you have a motion only around the local (rotated) x-axis. This translate into motions along both x and y global axes. Similarly, if you move along the local y axis, you move globally in both x and y global.
$$x_G=x_L\cos\theta-y_L\sin\theta+x_A\\y_G=x_L\sin\theta+y_L\cos\theta+y_A$$
I assumed that you measure the angle from the x-axis.
You would see these relationship easily, if you would draw a picture

Comment: Actually I mistyped my intitial formula when pasting it here, it actually was: GlobalXMotion = Math.cos(Rotation)*XMotion; GlobalYMotion = Math.sin(Rotation)*XMotion;

This is assuming I only need to move on the X axis locally, not both axises. That code is still wrong. ANd just making sure, what does X A mean at the end?
Rotation is a number 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: $x_A$ and $y_A$ are the initial positions of object A. Your formula is correct if you don't move in what I think is the "D" motion. But all this discussion is useless if you are using a different convention for motion axes. That's why you **must** provide a picture.